# Catalyst app crashes when using WheelPickerStyle()

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have a Catalyst version of my app written on SwiftUI. There is a picker which I wanted to be styled as WheelPickerStyle(). Mac Catalyst supports WheelPickerStyle():
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/wheelpickerstyle
At launch app crashes. With other styles everything works fine.

```
2021-05-20 11:04:48.341319+0300 Н или НН[2745:66389] [General] UIPickerView is not supported when running Catalyst apps in the Mac idiom.
2021-05-20 11:04:48.350037+0300 Н или НН[2745:66389] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff205fd87b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20335d92 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4544dc52 -[UIView(UICatalystMacIdiomUnsupported_Internal) _throwForUnsupportedNonMacIdiomBehaviorWithReason:] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff45158fe4 -[UIPickerView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff44578d14 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 759
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4452dfa1 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 130
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4452de1a -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 800
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4452cbcd -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1957
    8   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff565f2e0b $s7SwiftUI11DisplayListV11ViewUpdaterC010updateItemE033_C85E9C9D8E8767197A33852BB19DA7BELL9container4from10localStateyAE9ContainerAGLLVz_AC0H0VAE5ModelO0U0VztF + 971
    9   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff565f2861 $s7SwiftUI11DisplayListV11ViewUpdaterC015updateInheritedE033_C85E9C9D8E8767197A33852BB19DA7BELL9container4from11parentStateyAE9ContainerAGLLVz_AC4ItemVSPyAE5ModelO0U0VGtF + 867
    10  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff565f2179 $s7SwiftUI11DisplayListV11ViewUpdaterC6update33_C85E9C9D8E8767197A33852BB19DA7BELL9container4from11parentStateyAE9ContainerAGLLVz_ACSPyAE5ModelO0T0VGtF + 513
    11  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff565f1e5f $s7SwiftUI11DisplayListV11ViewUpdaterC6render04rootE04from4time7version10maxVersion13contentsScaleAA4TimeVSo6UIViewC_AcnC0M0VAR12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVtFANSPyAE5ModelO5StateV7GlobalsVGXEfU_ + 314
    12  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff565f1ce8 $s7SwiftUI11DisplayListV11ViewUpdaterC6render04rootE04from4time7version10maxVersion13contentsScaleAA4TimeVSo6UIViewC_AcnC0M0VAR12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVtF + 670
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff566ba9ee $s7SwiftUI11DisplayListV12ViewRendererC6render04rootE04from4time8nextTime7version10maxVersion13contentsScaleAA0L0VSo6UIViewC_Ac2oC0O0VAS12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVtF + 110
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff56277796 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC17renderDisplayList_4time8nextTime7version10maxVersionAA0J0VAA0fG0V_A2jL0M0VANtF + 230
    15  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff56832579 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_ + 4674
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5682c3f2 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtF + 350
    17  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5699d5e2 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyF + 241
    18  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5699d600 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyFTo + 21
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff44580013 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2925
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff26d058d3 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 326
    21  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff26d05239 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 619
    22  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff26e5107f _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 655
    23  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff26ce70df _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 713
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff44661e14 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 81
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20583512 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff205833c3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 440
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2058209d __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2058164c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff287bfab3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff287bf815 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 587
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff287bf5b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d826f2 _DPSNextEvent + 864
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d80ec5 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1364
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d73239 -[NSApplication run] + 586
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d4747c NSApplicationMain + 816
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff2303e414 _NSApplicationMainWithInfoDictionary + 16
    37  UIKitMacHelper                      0x00007fff3405ed47 UINSApplicationMain + 1430
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff444cc98c UIApplicationMain + 144
    39  –Э –Є–ї–Є –Э–Э                      0x00000001088fee4b main + 75
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff204a5f5d start + 1
    41  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can u checkout [forbidden-controls-in-catalyst-mac-](https://steipete.com/posts/forbidden-controls-in-catalyst-mac-idiom/)

Comment: Saw the same issue

Comment: Can someone explain why you would build a SwiftUI app using Mac Catalyst instead of building it as a native Mac app? Isn't one of the benefits of SwiftUI that one set of UI code is all that is needed for both iOS and macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I came for a different error.
I got similar for **.refreshable.** So I wrote a custom modifier.

Hope can help.

```
// MARK:   Refreshable - Modifier for Refreshable based on OS:

// accesory:
public func isCatalyst()->Bool {
    //tolerate warnings!

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    return true
#endif
    return false
}


public typealias RefreshAction = ()->()

private struct MyRefreshableModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    internal init(action: @escaping RefreshAction) {
        self.action = action
    }
    
    private let action: RefreshAction
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
#if os(iOS)
        // Catalyst IS under iOS:
        
        if isCatalyst(){
            content
        }else{
            content
            .refreshable {
                action()
            }
        }

#elseif os(macOS)
        content
        // nada. We throw away
        #endif
    }
}



public extension View {
    func portableRefreshableModifier(action: @escaping RefreshAction) -> some View {
        modifier(MyRefreshableModifier(action: action) )
    }
}


// usage:
/*

 List {
     Text("Hello World")
     Text("Hello World")
     Text("Hello World")
    }.refreshable {
     print("refresh....")
 }
  will be:
 List {
     Text("Hello World")
     Text("Hello World")
     Text("Hello World")
 }.portableRefreshableModifier {
     print("refresh....")
 }
*/
```